# Shell script: \n related problem to split a straightforward line

Tags: shell-script

That's an shell script snippet:

```
KVS_VARIABLES=$(awk -F= '!($1 && $2 && NF==2) { print "File failed validation on line " NR | "cat 1>&2"; next } { print $1, $2 }' $ENV_FILE_LOCATION)
echo ${KVS_VARIABLES}

for kv in ${KVS_VARIABLES}
do
  echo $kv
  key=$(echo $kv | awk -FS=" " '{print $1}')
  value=$(echo $kv | awk -FS=" " '{print $2}')

  echo "key: $key | value: $value"
done
```

I expect an output like:

```
key: VAR1 | value: VAL1
...
```

However, I'm getting that:

```
VAR1 VAL1 VAR2 VAL2 VAR3 VAL3
VAR1
key: VAR1 | value: 
VAL1
key: VAL1 | value: 
VAR2
key: VAR2 | value: 
VAL2
key: VAL2 | value: 
VAR3
key: VAR3 | value: 
VAL3
key: VAL3 | value:
```

**EDIT**

```
$ echo "$KVS_VARIABLES" ->
VAR1 VAL1
VAR2 VAL2
VAR3 VAL3
```

Comment: if you use double quotes like this.. then are you getting the one key value in each row ?   echo "${KVS_VARIABLES}"

Comment: paste the output of echo "${KVS_VARIABLES}"    ---> (use double quotes)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51077172/4957508

Comment: A simpler way to print to stderr from awk: `print "some string" > "/dev/stderr"`

Comment: You'll want to read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?" The first advice is "Don't try to use "for". Use a while loop and the read command. "

Comment: Also read https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667 about the importance of quoting variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify **IFS** as `newline`, by default input file separator (`IFS)` includes a space and hence your for loop is behaving this way

```
KVS_VARIABLES=$(awk -F= '!($1 && $2 && NF==2) { print "File failed validation on line " NR | "cat 1>&2"; next } { print $1, $2 }' $ENV_FILE_LOCATION)
echo ${KVS_VARIABLES}
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for kv in ${KVS_VARIABLES}
do
  echo $kv
  key=$(echo $kv | awk  '{print $1}')
  value=$(echo $kv | awk  '{print $2}')    
  echo "key: $key | value: $value"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

KVS_VARIABLES=$(echo -e "VAR1 VAL1\nVAR2 VAL2\nVAR3 VAL3\n")
echo "KVS_VARIABLES=[${KVS_VARIABLES}]"

while read -r kv; do
        echo "kv = ${kv}"
        key=$(echo $kv | awk '{print $1}')
        value=$(echo $kv | awk '{print $2}')

        echo "key: ${key} | value: ${value}"
done <<< "${KVS_VARIABLES}"
```

You should get

```
KVS_VARIABLES=[VAR1 VAL1
VAR2 VAL2
VAR3 VAL3]
kv = VAR1 VAL1
key: VAR1 | value: VAL1
kv = VAR2 VAL2
key: VAR2 | value: VAL2
kv = VAR3 VAL3
key: VAR3 | value: VAL3
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Arushix points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452378/116858), one of the issues with the code is that `read` splits the input on the values in the shell variable `IFS` (space, tab and newline by default).

However, I can't help but notice that your are parsing the variables in the original file several times; first by the first `awk` script, and then again with the `read`, and finally a third time with `echo`+`awk`.  Each of these steps may throw its own set of errors.

If you just want to validate the variable assignments and print out the key/value pairs:

```
if ! awk -F '=' 'NF != 2 { exit 1 } { printf("key: %s | value: %s\n", $1, $2) }' "$conffile"; then
    echo 'Failed' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Given the input file

```
VAR1=VAL1
VAR2=VAL2
VAR3=VAL3
VAR4=VAL4
```

This will print

```
key: VAR1 | value: VAL1
key: VAR2 | value: VAL2
key: VAR3 | value: VAL3
key: VAR4 | value: VAL4
```

With an extra line reading just `BOO` at the end of the input file, the output would instead be

```
key: VAR1 | value: VAL1
key: VAR2 | value: VAL2
key: VAR3 | value: VAL3
key: VAR4 | value: VAL4
Failed
```

In addition to `NF == 2`, you may want to include a check for valid variable names etc.:

```
if ! awk -F '=' 'NF != 2 || $1 !~ /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+$/ { exit 1 } { printf("key: %s | value: %s\n", $1, $2) }' "$conffile"; then
    echo 'Failed' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```